# Displaying Cards Side by Side

Tags: c++, formatting

I have to create a deck of cards to be used to make poker. I have created the cards to look like this when printed out on screen:

```
----------
|K       |
|        |
|        |
|        |
|        |
|        |
|        |
|        |
|       K|
----------
```

I have the card output defined as so:

```
void deck::cardKing(){
cout << "----------" << endl;
cout << "|K " << setw(7) << "|" << endl;
cout << "|" << setw(9) << "|" << endl;
cout << "|" << setw(9) << "|" << endl;
cout << "|" << setw(9) << "|" << endl;
cout << "|" << setw(9) << "|" << endl;
cout << "|" << setw(9) << "|" << endl;
cout << "|" << setw(9) << "|" << endl;
cout << "|" << setw(9) << "|" << endl;
cout << "|" << setw(9) << "K|" << endl;
cout << "----------" << endl;
}
```

My problem is that as of right now when I print out the entire deck they are in a line down (vertically) like so:

```
----------
|3       |
|        |
|        |
|        |
|        |
|        |
|        |
|        |
|       3|
----------
----------
|10      |
|        |
|        |
|        |
|        |
|        |
|        |
|        |
|      10|
----------
----------
|K       |
|        |
|        |
|        |
|        |
|        |
|        |
|        |
|       K|
----------
```

when I need to display them like so:

```
---------  ---------
|K      |  |2      |
|       |  |       |
|       |  |       |
|       |  |       |
|       |  |       |
|       |  |       |
|       |  |       |
|       |  |       |
|      K|  |      2|
---------  ---------
```

What would be the best method to get the cards to display horizontally instead of vertically? Could I use a picture of a card instead of just printing them out on the screen?

Comment: You'd either need a loop to draw all of your cards at once, or getting a capability to control the terminal cursor position. The latter can't be done using standard c++ functions, you'll need a library like _ncurses_ to do that.

Comment: 'Could I use a picture of a card' well, with a GUI framework, Qt say, it would be easy.

Comment: @MartinJames my professor showed us an example one someone displaying a picture of card in the terminal on linux. This project is in the terminal, is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 1):

One way around this would be to gather up the contents of each line

```
enum { eEdge, eTop, eMid, eBot, eMax };
std::ostringstream cardline[eMax];
```

For each card, instead of writing to the screen, update the cardline

```
void Deck::CardKing()
{
    cardline[eEdge] << "---------  ";
    cardline[eTop]  << "|K      |  ";
    cardline[eMid]  << "|       |  ";
    cardline[eBot]  << "|      K|  ";
}
```

Then when you need to print

```
std::cout << cardline[eEdge].str() << std::endl;
std::cout << cardline[eTop].str() << std::endl;
for (int ii = 2; ii < 9; ++ii)
    std::cout << cardline[eMid].str() << std::endl;
std::cout << cardline[eBot].str() << std::endl;
std::cout << cardline[eEdge].str() << std::endl;
```

Then, when you want a new line of cards

```
for (int ii = 0; ii < eMax; ++ii)
    cardline[ii].str();
```